# Can I sort the order of multiple authors in a single citation?

Tags: biblatex, citing, sorting

I'd like to have multiple authors like in

```
@book{three14,
    Author = {Au and Ca and Ba},
    Year = {2014}
}
```

appear as **(Au, Ba, and Ca, 2014)** (notice the sorting). But they will not be sorted and I could not find an option in the biblatex manual. Is there a solution to that?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite{three14}      

%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Authors should appear exactly as they are in the cited reference.

Comment: Good evening egreg. My institution requires me to cite like that, so I will have to find a solution.

Comment: I sympathize with you for having to adhere to stupid requirements. Probably adding an additional field with the authors in alphabetic order, with some `\DeclareSourceMap` sorcery can do. Should the authors be in alphabetical order also in the bibliography? If so, just rewrite the fields.

Comment: I'll read about that!

Comment: Are you really, really sure you need to do this? Institutions do have odd requirements but they are not normally positively at odds with good scholarship, even if they they are frequently at odds with good typography. It really is wrong to cite in this way. In my discipline, author order is normally without meaning and co-authors usually give their names alphabetically. But in the sciences, that is not the case at all. Moreover, even in my discipline, if authors were **not** in alphabetical order, that **might** have meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Currently `biblatex` does not allow to sort name lists. It would probably not be impossible to implement this in Biber, or even from within TeX (though that would likely be harder). (Though Biber offers some amazing features with its sort mapping, I don't see a way to sort using RegExp at the moment.)

It is, however, very unusual to sort name lists. Normally the names should appear as listed on the work itself. In some fields the order of authors conveys meaning.